# Preferred user language in C++ program

Tags: c++, localization

What is the proper way in standard C++ to query the preferred user language, e.g. en_US?

The Win32 API includes a beautifully named function `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` that does exactly this, but I want to be cross-platform and do it with facilities provides by the standard C++ library.

Comment: "What is the proper way in standard C++ to query the preferred user language" - there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) is a very similar standard library construct, where constructing it with an empty string produces what's believed to be the *user's preferred locale*.

`std::locale("").name()`, for example, might produce `en_US.UTF8`